# Error while connecting Django with sql server database

Tags: python, sql-server, django, database-connection

Im using mssql as the backend for the database.In the setting.py file,I need to use the host name with backslash. Due to this, I got the timed out error.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'xxxxx',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'HOST': 'aaa\bbb',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
        },
    }
}
```

Is there any way i could use the backslash in the host name.
Thanks in advance.Please help me sort out.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash may be acting as an escape character. `Try 'HOST': 'aaa\\bbb',`